# Hide emacs frame until loaded

Tags: init-file, frames, start-up

In my init.el file, I have some code to hide the Emacs toolbar:

```
;;; Hide the toolbar
(tool-bar-mode -1)
```

But when I load Emacs, it first enables the toolbar, and then quickly hides it, after it reads through my init.el file. This alone is a small annoyance. But my init.el file is getting pretty long. And now Emacs must go through a whole series of spastic *corrections*, every time it loads...

Is there a way to make Emacs process init.el *before* it launches the first frame?

I am on a Mac, running MacPorts Emacs, version 24.5.4.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, run `emacs --daemon` and then open a frame via `emacsclient`

Check the command-line options for each executable.

e.g. You can use `emacsclient -a '' -c` to start the server (if necessary) and open a GUI frame, in a single command.

Comment: Thanks phils. Sorry, I probably should have specified that I am on a Mac, running the aqua version of Emacs from mac-ports (I just added this to the post). I tried running emacs --daemon from terminal but got an Unknown option `--daemon` message? Running emacsclient -a '' -c" from Terminal failed...

Comment: I don't know anything about Aqua, but it's surprising to me if it doesn't support the normal command line options. What does `emacs --version` tell you? The `--daemon` option was added in GNU Emacs 23.1.

Comment: Okay, the version available from Terminal is 22.1.1. But this is what comes with OS X Yosemite. I installed the macports version separately, which launches like any other Mac app, with its own GUI...

Comment: Do some searching for how to ensure you always use the right version of Emacs in OSX -- I think this is a common problem.

Comment: Assuming aquamacs is named `Emacs.app` and is installed in `/Applications`, the binary is in `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs`. Adjust for your circumstances if necessary.

Comment: So I tried just now, with vanilla GNU Emacs built from development source on OS X: `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -q --daemon` followed by `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/emacsclient -c somefile` opened up `somefile` in a new frame. (I get an error if I start without `-q`, probably due to some mistake in my init file. It doesn't happen if I start normally.)

Answer (score 1):

By placing `(tool-bar-mode -1)` at the very **top** of `.emacs` or `init.el`, the toolbar will be removed **before** processing other user-configurations.

This solution/workaround was tested with Emacs version 24.5.1 (built `--with-ns`) from https://emacsformacosx.com/

[My eyes are unable to detect the presence of a toolbar while starting Emacs GUI using this method.]

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but could still see the jump. And this only gets compounded as the user add further customizations. What I was hoping for is some way to hide the GUI until after init.el is processed. I think of other apps that use a spash screen popup, which lets the user know that "it's working on it" but hides all the setup until it's ready...

Comment: Do you have the function `ns-hide-emacs` in the MacPorts version of Emacs on your computer?  If so, you may wish to try hiding/minimizing Emacs at the outset (**top**) of your `.emacs` / `init.el` and then unhide/activate the app at the very end of your `.emacs` / `init.el`.  Here is the doc-string:  "*ns-hide-emacs is a built-in function in 'C source code'.  (ns-hide-emacs ON)  If ON is non-nil, the entire Emacs application is hidden.  Otherwise if Emacs is hidden, it is unhidden.  If ON is equal to ‘activate’, Emacs is unhidden and becomes the active application.*"

Comment: Actually, I just tried that and the frame is visible for a split second before hiding it.  I'm going to leave that comment, so we have a record of what has been tried.

Comment: Brilliant! I couldn't get this to work though... tried `(ns-hide-emacs)` and `(ns-hide-emacs t)`. Sorry - eLisp is not my forte. Hey, what about tying this to the `emacs-startup-hook`?

Comment: The `before-init-hook` is too soon.  The `after-init-hook` is too late.  And the `emacs-startup-hook` is way way too late.  :)  I am curious as to why I cannot duplicate your issue with a bare-bones `.emacs` file that only contains `(tool-bar-mode -1)` using the version of Emacs from https://emacsformacosx.com/  I see the frame-title changing, and I see the buffers changing (with a scoll-bar being added) -- but I do not see the tool-bar.

Comment: I tried adding this to the top of my `init.el` file: `(add-hook 'before-init-hook (lambda () (make-frame-invisible)))` followed by `(add-hook 'after-init-hook (lambda () (make-frame-visible)))`. Also tried the `before-make-frame-hook`. No dice (as predicted :)... Strange, you would think that `before-make-frame-hook` would fire before the first frame arrives...?

Comment: How about trying `(add-to-list 'initial-frame-alist '(tool-bar-lines . 0))` at the very **top** of your `.emacs` / `init.el` file?

Comment: Didn't work... but it did lead me to this page: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Initial-Parameters.html which describes my problem exactly (see at the top under User Option: initial-frame-alist). It says that the frame will start with a default  state and then later conform to the initial-frame params specified. Also suggests that a way around this is to modify the `.Xresources` file?

Comment: Ah . . . thank you.  Short of modifying `startup.el` before building Emacs, I am out of ideas at the moment -- `startup.el` is baked-into the Emacs executable.  I am not familiar with modifying OSX frames at the system level.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. Was there more to your last comment? Was just about to dive into this..

Comment: I use a custom `startup.el` and build my own Emacs.  The function at issue in `startup.el` is `frame-initialize` (from `frame.el`) which apparently gets called before reading `site-start.el` (if it exists) and before reading `.emacs` / `init.el`.  Essentially, you probably need to add the parameter to the `initial-frame-alist` or `default-frame-alist` before `startup.el` calls `frame-initialize`.

Comment: Alright! Sorry, where can I find this file? Not in .emacs.d...?

Comment: `M-x find-library RET startup RET`  But, it has to be modified before building Emacs because it gets baked into the executable.  I don't have an easier option to propose at the moment.

Comment: Thanks! I found startup.el.gz. Also .elc? Do I need to re-compile the .el.gz file after making changes? Do you know how to do this? Thanks again!

Comment: When the executable is being built, `loadup.el` loads `frame.el` and `startup.el` and both are baked-into the executable -- `frame.el` contains `frame-initialize` and that is used by `startup.el`.  During startup, Emacs does not read those Lisp libraries because the contents are already included internally, so modifying them (after the build) will not help in this instance.  The suggested hack by Gilles (alternative answer) of modifying `subdirs.el` is probably as close as you can get without modifying the source code prior to building Emacs -- e.g., `.../site-lisp/subdirs.el`

Answer (score 1):

Under X11 (i.e. mainstream Unix), you can set GUI-related parameters via [X resources](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/X-Resources.html#X-Resources). To disable toolbars:

```
Emacs.toolBar: 0
```

This does not apply to a native Mac program. You can set some GUI parameters through [user defaults](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/defaults.1.html) (see examples of `defaults write org.gnu.Emacs …` [in the Emacs Wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsForMacOS)), but I don't know if there's one about the toolbar.

Looking at the [Emacs startup process](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Startup-Summary.html#Startup-Summary), if you want to execute code before the initial frame is opened, you have a few choices. None of them are really intended to do what you want to do but it should work nonetheless. All of them involve changing a file in the directory which is on the load path before your init file runs. You can add load path directories by setting the environment variable [`EMACSLOADPATH`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Library-Search.html#index-EMACSLOADPATH-environment-variable). In one of those directories, edit or create `subdirs.el` and add the line

```
(setq tool-bar-mode 0)
```

This does not affect existing frames, but we're doing this before any frames are started, so I think it will work (but I haven't tested). It may help to also have

```
(setq default-frame-alist (cons '(tool-bar-lines . 0) default-frame-alist))
(setq initial-frame-alist (cons '(tool-bar-lines . 0) initial-frame-alist))
```

But rather than seek this, I would just [start the Emacs daemon](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/24703) at session startup and then open windows in the existing session as needed.

Comment: Thanks Gilles! I was able to get this done by adding the following code to my /Applications/Emacs/MacOS/Resources/lisp/subdirs.el file: `(add-to-list 'initial-frame-alist '(visibility . nil))` followed by `(add-hook 'after-init-hook (lambda () (make-frame-visible)))` . The one drawback to this is that, if emacs is ever updated, this code will be lost. I tried creating a subdirs.el file in `/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp` but this was not read... no idea why?

Comment: @Adam Is this directory on the default load path? Run `emacs -Q` and check `load-path`

Comment: Ah! No, it's not. Do you know if it's possible to add a directory to the load-path that will stick the next time Emacs loads? Thanks again!

Comment: @Adam Normally you set `load-path`… but you have to modify a file that's already on the load path to do that! There may be some other path that's set up by the system files, check `load-path` in `emacs -q` (as opposed to `emacs -Q`). If you can't find a suitable location, you can set the environment variable `EMACSLOADPATH`.