# How can I make the initial frame invisible?

Tags: frames, start-up, x-resources

Using the following command line causes Emacs to briefly display the initial frame, then hide it:

```
emacs -Q --eval "(setq initial-frame-alist '((visibility . nil)))"
```

This is consistent with [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Initial-Parameters.html#Initial-Parameters):

> If these settings affect the frame geometry and appearance, you’ll see the frame appear with the wrong ones and then change to the specified ones. If that bothers you, you can specify the same geometry and appearance with X resources; those do take effect before the frame is created. See X Resources in The GNU Emacs Manual.

Which X resource should I use to make the initial frame invisible? Is there a cross-platform way to do so? On GNU/Linux, how can I set these resources for the duration of a single command?

Comment: The link to the following thread indicates a way to hack Emacs by adding something to `subdirs.el`, which is read by Emacs prior to reading the built-in `startup.el` (which we all know cannot be modified after building Emacs from source):  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/24724/2287  Perhaps you can do the same?  The comments throughout the thread give a better picture as to what is going on.

Comment: Interesting! However, it seems to require modifying a file, which seems heavy for something that will just be temporary :/

Comment: what are you trying to do? if you run emacs as `emacs --daemon` it loads your init but stays hidden. Then you can instantly create new frames with `emacsclient` when you need them.